# Size of frame gets larger

Tags: processing

Size of frame gets larger when arrow keys (+,-) are pressed while T is pressed simultaneously, the entire frame gets larger (Black Borders Increase) while the "picture" gets smaller.

```
color c=color(0); 

int strokeW=1,flag=0;

void setup() {
size(600, 600);
background(255);
}

void draw() {
fill(c);
stroke(c);
strokeWeight(strokeW);
if(flag==1) line(mouseX, mouseY, pmouseX, pmouseY); 
}

void mouseDragged() { 
flag=1;
}
void mouseReleased(){ 
flag=0;
}


void keyPressed() {
if (keyCode == UP) strokeW++;
if (keyCode == DOWN) strokeW--;

if (key == 'c') 
background(255);

if (key == 't') {
    fill(255,10); // semi-transparent white
  rect(0,0,width,height);

  fill(0);
  //line(mouseX, mouseY, , 100);
}


if (strokeW<0)strokeW=1; 
if(key== 'b')
c = color(random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255)); 
}
```

Comment: I've run your program and I still have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change this fragment (1):

```
    if (key == 't') {
        fill(255,10); // semi-transparent white
        rect(0,0,width,height);

        fill(0);
    }
```

into (2):

```
    if (key == 't') {
        fill(255,10); // semi-transparent white
        stroke(255);
        strokeWeight(0);
        rect(0,0,width,height);

        fill(0);
    }
```

In (1) you draw rect with **current** `stroke` and `strokeWeight` values. In each animation frame, inside `draw()` method, there is:

```
    stroke(c);
    strokeWeight(strokeW);
```

which set stroke weight to `strokeW`. When you press `'t'` letter - this **current strokeW** is used for as your`rect(0,0,width,height)` **border** ...